# Instagram API realtime subscriptions

Tags: php, instagram

So I have followed [this tutorial](http://thegregthompson.com/instagram-real-time-api-php/) and everything is working but now I'm kind of confused how to get the response with picture data if I want to subscribe to a tag?

Comment: please show some source... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: I don't think you do.  It looks like it just pings you that 'something new has been added' and it's then up to you as to whether you want to go out to get it.  It doesn't seem to give you the info.  You need to go get it after being told it's there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it raised some questions at my end to.

When the notification for let's say a tag subscription is pushed to your application you can now request the tag/media/recent when you do this save the, min_tag_id value found under 'pagination'

now for every new notification request the tag/media/recent?min_tag_id={YOUR_MIN_ID} this will only return the newest submissions for this tag.